# Django rest-auth registration error after creating new user. account_confirm_email not found

Tags: django, url, django-rest-framework, django-registration, django-rest-auth

I am creating a registration system with Django `rest-auth` and `allauth`. Looking at the documentation endpoints, I just used:

### urls.py

```
app_name = "apis"

urlpatterns = [

    path('users/', include('users.urls')),
    path('rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
    path('rest-auth/customlogin', CustomLoginView.as_view(), name='rest_login'),
    path('rest-auth/customlogout', CustomLogoutView.as_view(), name='rest_logout'),
    
    path('rest-auth/registration/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),

]
```

when I run, a browseable API appears like below:

[image]

After entering the details and post it, the below error occurs:

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'account_confirm_email' not found. 'account_confirm_email' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

is there another URL i need to implement (with the name of account_confirm_email) ?

I have read the documentations and `rest-auth` demos on this and it seems I need to include the following urls:

```
url(r'^verify-email/$', VerifyEmailView.as_view(), name='rest_verify_email'),
    url(r'^account-confirm-email/(?P<key>[-:\w]+)/$', TemplateView.as_view(), name='account_confirm_email'),
```

but this still did not fix the error why is that?

Comment: hello, i have a similar problem and i need your Help

Comment: but first, I am guessing you were trying to make this fully rest and not use a template? how did you override this view/url to handle it in your API client

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was adding this url:

```
url(r'^account-confirm-email/(?P<key>[-:\w]+)/$', TemplateView.as_view(), name='account_confirm_email'),
```

in the user app's `urls.py` rather than the project's `urls.py`. why is it that it cases the issue?